# align li to be left middle and right

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to set a navbar without using bootstrap navbar in CSS, I have it working when its displaying in md but I want to have 3 li within container when displaying in xs, the first being totally on the left, the second totally centered and the third being totally on the right. I have it working to a point but  cannot get the second or middle one to be in the center if that makes any sense. The code I am using is :

```css
#nav-xs {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 72px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00a4ff;
  float: left;
}

#nav-xs-left {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

#nav-xs-right {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav-xs-center {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#xs-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid f2p-nav-xs hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-sm">
  <ul id="xs-nav">
    <li id="nav-xs-left"><a href='login.php' class='btn btn-login' role='button'>Login </a></li>
    <li id="nav-xs-center"><a href='login.php' class='btn btn-login' role='button'>Login </a></li>
    <li id="nav-xs-right"><a href='login.php' class='btn btn-login' role='button'>Login </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

thankyou for any help I get

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: flex;` on the `ul`, with `justify-content: space-between;`:

```css
#nav-xs {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 72px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00a4ff;
  float: left;
}

#nav-xs-left {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

#nav-xs-right {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav-xs-center {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#xs-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid f2p-nav-xs hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-sm">
  <ul id="xs-nav">
    <li id="nav-xs-left"><a href='login.php' class='btn btn-login' role='button'>Login </a></li>
    <li id="nav-xs-center"><a href='login.php' class='btn btn-login' role='button'>Login </a></li>
    <li id="nav-xs-right"><a href='login.php' class='btn btn-login' role='button'>Login </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```